# XCode 4 errors/warnings dont jump to code when i click them

Tags: xcode, warnings

Hey this is a small issue with XCode 4 that is annoying me. When i click on warnings or compile errors on the left hand panel, I am not taken to where the error is on the code. This used to work in XCode 3.x but no more.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: This drives me crazy.  I don't consider it small, and I wish I knew what I could do about it.

Comment: This is basically the problem I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394429/xcode-4-issue-navigator-fails-on-files-outside-project-folder). I'm not entirely sure I got to the bottom of it but I'm seeing my errors in code now. Are you on 4.0.2? Also, does the Symbol Navigator work for you? For me, it works after I create a project but soon fails and never works again.

Comment: Are you using some ifndef preprocessor code somewhere? I think there may be a glitch with the line numbering when you use certain preprocessor commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ive found a way that works more often than not...

In the left hand panel, click on the "Show the log navigator", its the button which looks like a speech bubble. Now underneath will show the logs for every build. This is like the old Xcode, and will show errors/warnings. When you double click on the errors it will open the file to the line of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and fixed it by switching the compiler from `LLVM GCC 4.2` to `LLVM Version 2.0`.